# ¿ Como sumar columnas e insertarla en la ultima fila en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

señores ocupo ayuda. Necesito sumar las columnas de una consulta (pivoteo)
ejemplo en la img.
[image: Ejemplo de la conculta]

este es el código, el pivoteo funciona bien, solo que no logro sumar las columnas.

```
(select 
    T.Modelo,
     sum(IF(T.Operatividad='Operativo',T.Cantidad,0)) as 'Operativo',
     sum(IF(T.Operatividad='Inoperativo-Irrecuperable',T.Cantidad,0)) as 'Inoperativo_Irrecuperable',
    sum(IF(T.Operatividad='Inoperativo-Recuperable',T.Cantidad,0)) as 'Inoperativo_Recuperable',
    sum(IF(T.Operatividad='Desconocido',T.Cantidad,0)) as 'Desconocido', sum(T.Cantidad) as Total
   
  from (
 SELECT fuerza.nombre as Titulo,unidad.nombre as Unidad,concat(descrip_marcas,' ',modelo) as Modelo,count(*) as Cantidad,operatividad as Operatividad FROM logistica.Vehiculo
 join logistica.modelo on modelo.idmodelo = Vehiculo.modelo_idmodelo
 join logistica.marcas on marcas.idmarcas =  modelo.idmarca
 join logistica.operatividad on operatividad.idoperatividad = Vehiculo.idoperatividad
join logistica.unidad on unidad.idunidad = Vehiculo.idunidad
join logistica.fuerza on fuerza.idfuerza = unidad.idfuerza
where unidad.idfuerza =5
 group by concat(descrip_marcas,' ' ,modelo),unidad.nombre, operatividad
 order by Modelo,unidad.nombre
 ) as T
group by T.Modelo
order by T.Modelo) 
 union 
(SELECT 'Total',sum(Operativo),'','','','','','' from logistica.Vehiculo )
```

El error que aparece es que no existe la columna Operativo.
[image: Error de la consulta]

El resultado que busco es algo así con la suma en color naranja:
[image: Resultado deseado]

Gracias por su apoyo comunidad.

Comment: Ya resolví comunidad, el problema se debe que debo de repetir la misma consulta y luego  hacer la suma y después hacer la unión;

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví en `SQL Server`, no sé que tan distinto sea para `MySQL`.

La tabla inicial para mi era esta, denominada `sp1`:

| modelo | operativo | inoperativo | inoper2 | desconocido | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mod1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| mod2 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| mod3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| mod4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| mod5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

La consulta que usé fue:

```sql
INSERT INTO sp1
SELECT 'TOTAL', SUM(operativo), SUM(inoperativo), SUM(inoperativo2),
       SUM(desconocido), SUM(total)
FROM sp1
```

Resultando:

[image: TablaFinal]

Comment: Gracias pero el problema es cuando se hace pivoteo y al hacer un onion  no reconoce las variables de la tabla pivoteada